# Must go to goal A before you can go to goal B

Tags: java

My Problem is that I want my agent to find go to goal A before goal B. like in this example : In order to achieve a particular task an agent must go to goal a and then go to goal  B. In the event that the agent goes directly to B from the starting point, it has not successfully completed the game and need to visit A before visiting B.

I am applying this example to Reinforcement Learning:

This is in the Simulation.java class

At the moment my agent can go from its starting point to the goals state: Below is the current code to stop the agent if the isterminal method is called and maxStepsPerTrial has not been reached, it will then print out a sequence of steps it took

```
     for (stepnum = 1; !currState.isTerminal()

        && (stepnum < maxStepsPerTrial); stepnum++) {
            step(ep % printDivisor == 0);

            }
```

This is in the GirdState.java class:

This is the isTermial() so cr is a another class named Coloumns&Row where it holds the values for the goal row and goal coloumns.

```
 @Override
 public boolean isTerminal() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 return (y == cr.GOAL_ROW && x == cr.GOAL_COL);
 }
```

What I want it to do is before it can call isterminal(), it first must pass through a subgoal  E.g

```
   public boolean isSubA() {

    return (y == 3 && x == 3);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of a way of implementing this.

Comment: You could implement a "state machine" where each goal knows the next goal. With that an agent cannot skip goals. You can google for state machine implementations in Java. There should be plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Just give your object a new variable where he holds his current permissions?